# Keep my computer connected to the internet via ethernet and use usb wifi dongle to connect to my camera's built in wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, tethering

I was wondering if there is a way to keep my PC connected to the internet via ethernet but also use a usb wifi dongle to connect to my Nikon camera's built in wifi so that I can tether the camera and view photos taken and see them on the computer. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I'd seriously investigate USB tethering. Nikon's irritating habit of switching the WiFi off as soon as you stop using it for more than 2 minutes is enough to drive you insane. I occasionally tether mine to my phone, but only for projects taking minutes rather than hours. For everything else, I hard-wire. You can get 30m USB cables with in-built repeaters.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one network adapter in the computer.

The Ethernet connection will most certainly stay as the default route
for the internet.

You will need to address the camera via its IP address. To find the IP segment
of the camera, run in the Command Prompt the command
[ipconfig](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ipconfig).
This doesn't give the camera's IP which, if the camera itself does not show,
you will need to find by other means.