# Simultaneous connection to LAN and WiFi in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, camera

I tried to look for a similar topic and none really answered my doubts completely. Similar topic is here but without clear solution:

[Keep my computer connected to the internet via ethernet and use usb wifi dongle to connect to my camera's built in wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/1569834/keep-my-computer-connected-to-the-internet-via-ethernet-and-use-usb-wifi-dongle)

Anyway, apologies if I double the question. In our lab we have a Windows 10 computer for spectrophotometer control. It is connected to local network and Internet via LAN (static IP address). In addition, we are about purchase the Olympus EP50 camera with WiFi dongle module. The module produces WiFi signal and multiple devices can connect to it so one can display and save pictures from the camera. To be able to connect to the camera via WiFi from the same computer I added the TP-LINK wireless adapter (TL-WN722N) to the computer, installed its software and this seems to be working perfectly. However, when I connect to the camera via WiFi i lose access to the Internet. Is there any way for the computer to be simultaneously connected to the Internet via LAN and to the camera via WiFi? I looked in the Windows settings, but could not find a clear solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case because Windows has priorities with which network connection it uses [Ethernet > Wifi > Cellular], and because of this, the Wifi Adapter is disabled when you use ethernet.

You can try following these steps to override this priority, but be aware that editing the registry is not really a nice solution as these changes can be reverted by any future Windows update *(credit goes to an [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/wifi-disconnects-when-ethernet-is-plugged-in/00329022-6cad-4ea4-8a0a-ab1e38812e32) by [Kapil Arya MVP](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/f3af547a-1df3-4ec4-bbc3-536099f1db71), a helpful member of the Microsoft support team)*:

1. Open Registry Editor and go to:

   ```
   HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WcmSvc\Local
   ```
2. Create/change DWORD `fMinimizeConnections` to `0`
3. Close Registry Editor and reboot

Comment: Please use correct markdown for monospaced code

Answer (score 0):

Apart from keeping both connections active, which I guess was already answered, you will then need to make sure that you tell Windows networking how to reach each one of the networks accessible through each interface.

Having two interfaces active will cause your Windows machine to become a router, should the two networks reachable through each of the interfaces be different.

Your very Windows OS should know how to reach each one of the networks. You may need to set static routes though, should you want to get any further than the interface IP itself.

This tells Windows which interface to use to reach some IP address outside of it.
One of the networks, in your case probably the cabled one, will be the default gateway to get to the outside world (the Internet), while the other will be a dead end with the only purpose to access your IP camera.

Thus you will need some static routes:

1 - Some route to tell the OS how to reach the cabled network.
2 - One route to tell the OS how to reach the camera.
3 - One default gateway to tell the OS that the Internet should be reached through the cabled network.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/